# Disable keyboard input via FireBreath plugin on my web page

Tags: c++, plugins, web, input, firebreath

Can i somehow disable all keyboard input for user on my web page via plugin on that page? (plugin written with FireBreath)
 I don't need it to make user unable to input in some specific input field (I know, that it can be achieved another, lot more easier way), I just need to totally disable some keyboard keys input for web page, containing my plugin object, for some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot.  Pretty sure ActiveX controls cannot do this (in IE) and NPAPI plugins cannot preempt the browser in this way.

I guess there might be some possible way to do it using windows system API calls, since you can get the browser HWND, so maybe you could hijack the winproc, but I think you'd find it to be pretty fragile -- not to mention you'd likely tick off the people who maintain the browsers' plugin blacklists... Anyway, there is definitely no "normal" way to do it, so if there is a hack that would work it would involve some fairly complex API programming and is way beyond anything I know how to do.  You'd want to ask that as a windows api question instead of a plugin question.

On Mac there is absolutely no way to do it, since you have no way to access the window for the browser.  Linux is anybody's guess, but I suspect there is no way there either.